# How to insert data into table while looping in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert values in the loop to table but am not able do that since my function throwing error..

I want to insert data getting from select statment into base table Date_Dim.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_date_dimension(
OUT "date" date,
OUT week integer,
OUT quarter integer,
OUT dayname text,
OUT monthname text,
OUT year integer,
OUT month integer
) RETURNS SETOF RECORD STABLE LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
 $$DECLARE
 dat date;
 start_date timestamp := '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
 end_date timestamp := '2016-12-31 00:00:00';
 BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
   insert into date_dim
   SELECT
       d::date,
       date_part('week', d)::integer,
       date_part('quarter', d)::integer,
       to_char(d, 'day'),
       to_char(d, 'month'),
       date_part('year', d)::integer,
       date_part('month', d)::integer
     FROM generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day') d(d);
END;$$;
ERROR:  cannot open INSERT query as cursor
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_date_dimension() line 6 at RETURN QUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not select query. So return value should void like that

```
RETURNS VOID
```

instead of

```
RETURN QUERY
```

You also need to replace OUT with IN for parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the just inserted rows, you need to use `returning`

You can also simplify your function declaration by using `returns setof date_dim`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_date_dimension()
  RETURNS SETOF date_dim
  LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS
$$
DECLARE
 dat date;
 start_date timestamp := '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
 end_date timestamp := '2016-12-31 00:00:00';
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
   insert into date_dim
   SELECT
       d::date,
       date_part('week', d)::integer,
       date_part('quarter', d)::integer,
       to_char(d, 'day'),
       to_char(d, 'month'),
       date_part('year', d)::integer,
       date_part('month', d)::integer
     FROM generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day') d(d)
   returning *; --<< HERE
END;
$$
;
```